# HTTP POST can't find the ASP.NET MVC controller Method and bind the ViewModel to it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a lengthy ViewModel class that I POST to my Controller with an HTTPPost but the controller method doesn't catch it and instead in my browser console log I get HTTP 500 POST Error

Simplified my code is like this

```
public class MyDataViewModel{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    //etc to Property 100
}
```

cshtml:

```
<form action="@(Url.Action("Edit", "MyData"))" id="myform" class="myform" method="post">

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property1)
    //...

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property100)
```

Some properties make use of Data Annotations.

When I submit the from  the client side validation does work correctly and block the post before it is submitted if a required field is not captured.

However after the form submission my POST Method in my controller does not get hit. I verify this by putting a breakpoints on it as well as seeing the HTTP 500 error in my browser console log.

This is the method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(MyDataViewModel myDataViewModel)
{
```

However when I change it the method parameter to an object i.e.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(object myDataViewModel)
```

it does get hit. I then try to cast that object to `(MyDataViewModel)myDataViewModel` the casting fails so something isn't right.

I have looked through fiddler to confirm all those data properties are being sent and they are.

I then tried the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(object myDataViewModel)
    {



        Type myType = myDataViewModel.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object propValue = prop.GetValue(myDataViewModel, null);

            // Do something with propValue
        }
    }
```

To see if I could find which property has the issue. However `props.Count = 0` which means the object is empty. Why would fiddler show all those fields  but MVC not receive it? It makes no sense

I have the same type forms on other page that use the same `<form>` tags and method of posting which work so not sure why this one if failing.

In Visual Studio I can collapse the various html tags in the cshtml including the `<form>` tag so that doesn't pick up anything suspicious and shows each html tag has a corresponding closing tag.

Comment: Just a guess, but could it be because you're using `<form>` instead of `@Html.BeginForm()`?

Comment: I use the exact same form code in my other pages and they all work. It's only this one that doesn't work

Comment: Do the usual; check to make sure you have a </form> tag, check to make sure you don't have multiple forms nested. If that isn't the case, see where exactly it is posted using Fiddler and if necessary, re-post using fiddler, until you hit your action. Check your routing once you know where it is being posted. Check your controller name, change the interface of your Edit action -- Async and non-. Other than that, put the code besides the one that works and see where the differences are.

Comment: All signs are pointing to an exception during modelbinding. If possible, capture the POST request in Fiddler and post it here, along with your `MyDataViewModel`.

Comment: try renaming the variable being passed, instead of `myDataViewModel`, try using just `model`, it might be a naming conflict

Comment: Can you try commenting out like 95 of those inputs and get a successful post with just 5 of them? Using the strongly typed model in the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a dummy viewmodel, using this dummy view model type as the HTTPPost parameter, and putting in a few properties of the real viewmodel in at a time, compiling the solution, test, until I reach the point where it doesn't hit the POST controller method..

Took a while but I eventually found the culprit property.

```
    [Required, Display(Name = "Flag"),StringLength(50)]
    public bool IsFlag{ get; set; }
```

I used a data annotation  `StringLength` for a bool field which wasn't valid for a bool.

This resulted in the front end not showing any client validation jquery.validate error before HTTPPost and the HTTPPost method controller method unable to get hit.

I would still like to now if there is a quicker way to troubleshoot this type of issue or determine which property is at fault as the method I used was very laborious.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to put "public" in the post action. It puzzled me quite a while. Also, if there is some problem with the post action, it will enter the get action (if you don't specifically put HttpGet there) and it makes you wonder why I click the button but still goes to the get action.